# TouchListener getting called multiple times

Tags: android

I am new to android development and would like to create a simple game to learn the basics of android. I am trying to implement a TicTacToe game.

i am dynamically generating the 'X' and 'O' image at run time and placing the 'X' and 'O' on top of another image which shows the cell.

my code is 
https://github.com/vtkrishn/tictac/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vtkrishn/myapplication/landingActivity.java

on click of the 'New Game button' I will show the board and I am trying to find the x,y co-ordinates of the user touch event on the image. right now the initial 'O' will be placed randomly and after that 'X' will be placed by the user. I see that when user touches once the listener is getting called multiple times.

I am not sure why. Can any one help?
Also i wanted to place 'O' immediately after user presses the 'X' for that should I call the placeCircle method inside the touchListener?

Thanks,
Vinod!

image is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BMzb.png

Answer (score 0):

I think the listener is being called for both the ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP events. 
To have it only execute in one event, do something like this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

switch(event.getAction())
{
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         // code for event action DOWN
    break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // code for event action UP
    break;

  }

  // rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you must first call setontouchlistner(this);

after that make some thread or according to your requirement you must implement 
setontouchlistener(null);

after thread completing you again call setontouchlistener(this); it will work 




public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

switch(event.getAction())
{
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         // code for event action DOWN
    break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // code for event action UP
    break;

  }

  // rest of the code
}
```